# Efficiently writing large file contents to a text box/richbox without UI freezing in VB.NET

Tags: c#, vb.net

I am trying to write a large text file (containing more than several million characters) to a text box/richbox. if I write line by line using readline() and append it to textbox/richbox, it is taking an awful lot of time due to large file size. however if I do this, I can prevent UI freezing by a delegate function or by adding Application.DoEvents() inside the loop.

as I described before this method is not efficient for large files. I would like to use readtoend() and append it to textbox/richbox which seems to be far better than readline(). but this makes my UI to freeze until the process is completed.

is there a way to use readtoend() function without UI freezing ? I am unable to run this function on a seperate thread as i need to read the text in to my UI

using Visual studio 2010, .net 4.0

Comment: what framework version you are using ?

Comment: What is the purpose of adding more than several million characters to a textbox?

Comment: the contents of the textbox/richbox is standard outputstream data from a process. the purpose is for the user to find certain blocks of streams which they are interested in.

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```
    Dim myText= File.ReadAllText("filename");
    TextBox.Text = myText;
```

Comment: I tried but no luck..

Answer (score 0):

Simple answqer is: you do not do it. THe TextBox (in .NET - not in VB.NET) is not made to handle large amounts of data. SImple like that.

You will need some third party component that is done for that.

Comment: no you don't `RichTextBox` is capable of manipulating thousands of lines per second... just need custom handlers, and a background thread to pull the data.

Comment: I can use a richbox instead of textbox but how to pull the file contents efficiently without freezing my user interface (UI) ? my UI (richbox) is involved in the process so can I use a separate thread for this purpose ? could you explain with an example code.. (I am new to multi-threading)